# Relative addressing files python3

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have variable `address = /data/train/1.jpg`, and I'm trying to read file by

```
im = Image.open(address)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/train/1.jpg'
```

By some reasons I can't use full name of file.
I started jupyter notebook from folder which actually contains file 1.jpg in /data/train/.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative addressing means from the perspective of the current working directory. So if you script is in the same directory that the data folder is in, your path to the file would be `./data/train/1.jpg.` Note the `./`, which means the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

use relative path, this one is absolute

```
address = './data/train/1.jpg'
im = Image.open(address)
```

in this case ***.*** means current location while slash means the environments root (view and explanation) on this depends on your OS